# Play! framework project used as library dependency for second play project

Tags: java, web-services, playframework, dependencies, sbt

So I have two different play framework projects (micro-service A and service B). I want to use the models from A in B. So what I've done is include A as a dynamic library dependency in B (with jitpack). This compiles and the IDE is OK with it, however once B is started up, it uses the routes and controllers from A (completely ignoring B's routes file).

Is there a setting to tell play to ignore all but the current project routes file? Is there another way to use a project as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to define which application.conf to use for B project, add this line to your build.sbt of B project should resolve the issue you have:

```
Keys.javaOptions+="-Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf"
```

I don't recommend using Play project as dependency of other play projects, especially for micro-services project. It will be cleaner if you extract the common part used by both project into a separate jar module, and add as dependencies to both projects.

You might also want to check play's submodule document for running multiple play projects on the same server. 
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects

Comment: Is there somewhere specific in the order of the build.sbt that line needs to be added? It doesn't seem to be working for me. I've split most of the functionality out into a separate library, it's just the models are all full of JPA/hibernate stuff that seems like it could be problematic.